# OdbcConnection Text Driver ignores scheme.ini settings

Tags: c#, csv, odbc

Here is my code:

```
            OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection("Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};DSN=scrapped.csv");
        conn.Open();
        OdbcCommand foo = new OdbcCommand(@"SELECT * FROM [scrapped.csv] WHERE KWOTA < 100.00", conn);
        IDataReader dr = foo.ExecuteReader();
        StreamWriter asd = new StreamWriter("outfile.txt");
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            int cols = dr.GetSchemaTable().Rows.Count;
            for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++)
            {
                asd.Write(string.Format("{0};",dr[i].ToString()));
            }
            asd.WriteLine();
        }
        asd.Flush();
        asd.Close();
        dr.Close();
        conn.Close();
```

Here is my Scheme.ini

```
      [scrapped.csv]

Format=Delimited(;)
NumberDigits=2
CurrencyThousandSymbol= 
CurrencyDecimalSymbol=,
CurrencyDigits=2

Col1=DataOperacji Date
Col2=DataKsiegowania Date
Col3=OpisOperacji Text
Col4=Tytul Text
Col5=NadawcaOdbiorca Text
Col6=NumerKonta Text
Col7=Kwota Currency
Col8=SaldoPoOperacji Currency
```

Here I have sample from my CSV:

```
2013-01-22;2013-08-24;notmatter;"notmatter";"notmatter";'notmatter';7 111,55;10 222,20;
2013-03-26;2013-08-23;notmatter;"notmatter";"notmatter";'notmatter';-275,00;15 466,24;
```

So even if I have date and currency set in scheme.ini and regional settings (which should be used by odbc by defult but are not) values which i write to output file are total mess.

They are empty if there is space (my local thousend delimiter) and if I have value like 15,45 i got 15,4500 instead.

Date fields also behave abnormal, and even if I insert to scheme.ini `DateTimeFormat` I get  nothing like I specified in format.

Any help would be appreciated, what to do with it, I would like to use ODBC and query CSV data like database with `WHERE something = something`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a line to your schema.ini and ran against an adodb connection and it worked for me in the matter of dates, other bits are still not right. Note DateTimeFormat.

```
[scrapped.csv]
Format=Delimited(;)
NumberDigits=2
CurrencyThousandSymbol= 
CurrencyDecimalSymbol=,
CurrencyDigits=2
DateTimeFormat="yyyy-mm-dd"

Col1=DataOperacji Date
Col2=DataKsiegowania Date
Col3=OpisOperacji Text
Col4=Tytul Text
Col5=NadawcaOdbiorca Text
Col6=NumerKonta Text
Col7=Kwota Currency
Col8=SaldoPoOperacji Currency
```

You may also need:

```
ColNameHeader=False
MaxScanRows=0
```

But at the moment, I cannot see a way to get a space accepted as the CurrencyThousandSymbol

Comment: I get "2011-09-16 00:00:00" I thought I might get just "2011-09-16" and if I query
`SELECT * FROM [scrapped.csv] where (DataOperacji BETWEEN "2011-02-02" AND "2011-04-04")`
I get an data type error
`ERROR [22018] [Microsoft][ODBC Text Driver] Data type mismatch in criteria expression.`

Comment: Did you add the extra lines I suggested? Once I added them, I can run this `"SELECT * FROM [scrapped.csv] WHERE DataOperacji=#2013/03/26#"`

Comment: I've added those lines as well, and your query also works for me. Why hashtags? `#2013/03/26#` it looks like this format in query is ok while mine was nok. I am also, considering workaround to use currency as float values and don't worry about it. But for Float also I have problem with thousand separator, I can write script to remove spaces from two last cols, but it is soo hacky.

Comment: Hash tags are date delimiters for the Jet/Ace drivers, which is where the text driver is coming from. The only way I can imagine getting away with that space is in a text field.

Comment: I am just running such script against my csv, and after it I can use those values as float:
`File.open('out.csv', 'w') do |f2|  
 File.readlines('scrapped.csv').each do |line|
  arr = line.split(';')
  arr[arr.length-1] = arr[arr.length-1].delete(" ")
  arr[arr.length-2] = arr[arr.length-2].delete(" ")
  line2 = arr.join(";")
  f2.puts line2
 end
end`
 But it is not something I'd like to do every time ofc :)

Comment: Where are you putting this stuff? Import the currency as string, and convert afterwards.