# VBA Code - Import a text file into an Access table - With Condition

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I need to import a text file into an Access table, but using import conditions in TXT file.

Below is my VBA code. It works only when you do not use the WHERE clause, because it is asking for parameter entry. I think the problem is in the missing field format specification.

Which adjustments do you recommend? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

**TEXT FILE - Teste.txt**

```
1;24;433;43;5
2;436;424;43;24
3;5454;656;656;555
4;545;545;0;0
5;65465;756;0;0
```

**My Code VBA Access:**

```
Sub MyTableImport()

    Dim sqlStr As String

    sqlStr = "SELECT * INTO NewTable "
    sqlStr = sqlStr & " FROM [Text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited;Database=C:\Temp].Teste.txt "
    sqlStr = sqlStr & " WHERE field4 <> '0' AND field5 <> '0';"

    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    DoCmd.RunSQL sqlStr
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True

End Sub
```

Comment: You could simply omit the WHERE clause, and do a `DELETE * FROM NewTable WHERE field4 = '0' OR field5 = '0'` after the import.

Comment: Please do not use setwarnings it is unsafe and system wide. Use Execute against a databas instance instead.

Comment: You may need to use a schema.ini file if you have non-standard delimters http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12137085/changing-connection-string-in-excel-messes-up-column-data-types/12145949#12145949

Comment: @Fionnuala - According. I implemented a new version. Follow: `code` Dim sqlStr As String Dim db As DAO.Database db.Execute sqlStr, dbFailOnError db.Close`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used a `Schema.ini` approach, [as Fionnuala suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32390960/vba-code-import-a-text-file-into-an-access-table-with-condition/32397245#comment52657398_32390960), similar to what you had in one of the earlier versions of your question.

With your *Teste.txt* source file, and the *Schema.ini* and query below, this is the result for *NewTable*.  All five fields are text datatype:

[image]

This is *C:\Temp\Schema.ini*:

```
[Teste.txt]
ColNameHeader=False
Format=Delimited(;)
Col1="field1" Text
Col2="field2" Text
Col3="field3" Text
Col4="field4" Text
Col5="field5" Text
```

And this is the query which created *NewTable*:

```sql
SELECT t.field1, t.field2, t.field3, t.field4, t.field5
INTO NewTable
FROM [Text;HDR=No;FMT=Delimited;Database=C:\Temp].[Teste.txt] AS t
WHERE (((t.field4)<>'0') AND ((t.field5)<>'0'));
```

Comment: Perfect @HansUp /  @Fionnuala /  @Andre451. I put one more small piece of code to get the text file from within the own project. Follows:
`code`
Dim strFolder As String
strFolder = CurrentProject.Path
sqlStr = sqlStr & " FROM [Text;HDR=No;FMT=Delimited;Database=" & strFolder & "].Teste.txt AS t"

Comment: @HansUp I applied your approach in one of my projects but I get inconsistent results. Though I didn't use a text file as source but an `xlsb` Excel file I don't think that should be a problem (this is where I might be wrong). Appreciate if you can check it out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45211483/execute-method-does-not-consistently-execute-all-command-text), I just want to understand why it gives inconsistent results and hear your thoughts about it.